# Isomorphism between two modules which have an inner product and a $\mathbb{Z}_p[G]$ action

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, modules, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group (not necessarily abelian), let $\mathbb{Z}_p$ denote the p-adic integers and let $M$ and $N$ be two finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}_p$-modules, which are also $G$-modules. Assume in addition that there is a perfect bilinear pairing
 $$\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle : M\times N \to \mathbb{Z}_p$$
which for all $m \in M$, $n \in N$ and $g\in G$ satisfies
$$\langle m^g,n^g\rangle=\langle m,n\rangle^g$$
and
$$\langle m^g,n\rangle=\langle m,n^{g^{\ast}} \rangle,$$
where $*:\mathbb{Z}_p[G] \to \mathbb{Z}_p[G]$ is a certain involution. I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to show (maybe under some additional hypotheses, such as $M$ and $N$ are both free and finitely generated) that $M$ and $N$ are isomorphic as $\mathbb{Z}_p[G]$-modules?

For example, when $N$ is free and finitely generated, from the above we have that
$$ M \cong \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}_p}(N,\mathbb{Z}_p)$$
as $\mathbb{Z}_p[G]$-modules and 
$$\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}_p}(N,\mathbb{Z}_p) \cong N$$
as $\mathbb{Z}_p$ modules. Furthermore, a Corollary from Maschke's theorem asserts that if $L$ is a module defined over a field $K$ with characteristic not dividing $|G|$, then 
$$\mathrm{Hom}_{K}(L,K) \cong L$$
as $K[G]$-modules. So it seems that the result would be true if we worked over $\mathbb{Q}_p[G]$.

2. If the result in part 1) is true, can one extend it to infinite groups $G$?

Answer (score 1):

It is not true that the $K$-linear dual of a representation $L$ is isomorphic to $L$. For instance, if $K=\mathbf{C}$ is the field of complex numbers, then $L \cong L^*$ if and only if the characters are equal $$\chi_L=\chi_{L^*}$$ so since the character of the dual is the complex conjugate of the character of $L$, this happens if and only if the character of the representation of $L$ is real.

So you shouldn't expect this to be true over the $p$-adic integers, either, and it isn't. Take $G$ to be the cyclic group of order $3$, take $p=7$ so that $\mathbf{Z}_7$ contains a primitive third root of unity $\zeta$, and take $M=\mathbf{Z}_7$ with action of $G$ defined by letting a fixed generator $g$ act as multiplication by $\zeta$. The dual has $g$ acting by multiplication by $\zeta^{-1}$, hence is not isomorphic to $M$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not understand what am I mis-interpreting in the following theorem, then: If R is a semisimple ring, containing a field $K$ as a subring, R is f.d. over $K$ and $M$ is a fin. gen. R-module, then $M^{\ast}=\mathrm{Hom}_K(M,K)$ is R-isomorphic to $M$. So for $R=Q_p[G]$ and $K=Q_p$, it would imply the isomorphism that I claim, or not?

Comment: @E.Blioch I don't think that theorem is true. For one thing, how do you make $M^*$ a left $R$-module? It is only a right $R$-module in the generality you state. What is your reference?

Comment: It came up while googling, seems to be Theorem C.17 in Y. Bilu-The problem of Catalan.

Comment: Well, my google books won't let me look at the relevant pages! My guess is that there is a missing hypothesis in what you wrote, perhaps one that is standing in the book.

Comment: It is word by word the following: Let $R$ be a semi-simple (commutative) ring, containing a field $K$ as a subring. Assume that $R$ is of finite dimension over $K$, and let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module. Then $M^{\ast}=\mathrm{Hom}_{K}(M,K)$ is $R$-isomorphic to $M$. I assume that the (commutative) hypothesis is not required, but in your example it is commutative anyway.

Comment: I see the issue. The point is that the antipode is not needed if the ring $R$ is commutative: then for an $R$-module $M$ its $K$-dual is again a (left, or right, it makes no difference) $R$-module in the obvious way. But for a $G$-module, the way you change from a right module to a left module (even for abelian groups!) is by using the map $g \mapsto g^{-1}$.

Comment: I understand. However, in my case, G already acts via an involution as I described in the question. So if you want, taking the involution $g \to g^{-1}$ as simplest example, I have on one module the action via $g$ and on the dual via $g^{-1}$. If these are compatible, is it not still called $G$-isomorphism?

Comment: The point is that it really matters what the involution is!